# Use of dojo/select on non-AMD code

Tags: javascript, jquery-selectors, dojo, amd, sizzle

I have on my site legacy JavaScript that uses Sizzle as selector engine.

I recently added the dojo library (v 1.8) for visualization purposes (charts, etc.). Because dojo includes selectors (dojo/select), I am thinking that Sizzle is now redundant and that I could replace it with dojo/select. Is there a way to make dojo/select work with non-AMD code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Brandon Boone](https://stackoverflow.com/users/402706/brandon-boone)'s answer is very useful so you do not have to rewrite your selector strings. I think what you are asking for is how to export [`dojo/query`](http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dojo/query) into global namespace, i.e. into `window` object through asynchronous nature of AMD. There are two options:

1. If you use release version, it has `dojo/query` already packed in `dojo.js`, so you do not have to take care of asynchronous execution of module factory function, just *export* the variable:

   ```
   <script 
       src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.8.0/dojo/dojo.js"
       data-dojo-config="async:true"
   ></script>

   <script>
       // export query module to global namespace (window object)
       require(["dojo/query"], function(query) {
           window.query = query;        
       });
   </script>

   <script>
       // query function is now available globally
       console.log(query("li"));
   </script>
   ```

   See this example in action at jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/phusick/gvnGu/
2. If you use baseless dojo, it would be more tricky because you actually have to wait for `dojo/query` to load:

   ```
   <script src="dtk-sdk/dojo/dojo.js" data-dojo-config="async:true"></script>

   <script>
       // wrap your lecacy code into a function so it's not executed immediately
       var executeNonAmdCode = function() {
           console.log(query("li"));
       }
   </script>

   <script>
       require(["dojo/query"], function(query) {
           // export query module to global namespace (window object)
           window.query = query;
           // execute the legacy code
           executeNonAmdCode();
       });
   </script>
   ```

Answer (score 1):

[According to the docs](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/query.html) you can swap out the DOJO selector engine for AMD/Dojo compatible versions of [sizzle](https://github.com/kriszyp/sizzle) or [slick](https://github.com/kriszyp/slick). So if I were you, I'd keep Sizzle around and change dojo's underlying selector to Sizzle, removing the redundancy without having to touch legacy code.

> We can also use other selector engine levels. Both Sizzle and Slick
>   are excellent selector engines that work with dojo/query. AMD/Dojo
>   compatible versions (just wrapped with AMD) are available here:
>
> - https://github.com/kriszyp/sizzle
> - https://github.com/kriszyp/slick
>
> Once installed, you can use the selector engine module id as specified
>   selector engine level. We could set Sizzle as the query engine for our
>   page:
>
> ```
> <script data-dojo-config="selectorEngine: 'sizzle/sizzle'" src="dojo/dojo.js">
> </script>
> ```
>
> or set Slick as the engine for a particular module:
>
> ```
> define(["dojo/query!slick/Source/slick"], function(query){
>   query(".someClass:custom-pseudo").style("color", "red");
> });
> ```

Comment: Very interesting, thanks! I'll report back after I've tried it out. I am still not sure how to connect this to my non-AMD scripts.

Answer (score 0):

To add to @phusick's answer, I just learnt that starting with v1.8 dojo supports this:

```
<script type="dojo/require">
    "myApp.query": "dojo/query"
</script>
```

The above code will add the query method to the global myApp object (and create myApp if needed).

Source:

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/parser.html#dojo-parser